# Avoid globals in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global-variables

I made a simple code and my question is if is there a way to avoid globals in tkinter in this kind of scenario:

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Main')
root.minsize(400, 450)


toggle = True


def change_now():
    global toggle
    root.config(bg='blue') if toggle else root.config(bg='black')
    toggle = not toggle

my_button = Button(root, text='Click me!', command=change_now)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I know the best option is an object-oriented approach, but that means refactoring the entire code, is there a quick solution in this example? I know using global variables is bad practice.

Comment: You cannot avoid using global variables, `root` and `my_button` are also global variables.  Even using OOP, the instance of a class may still be global variable.  It is recommended to minimize the number of global variables.

Comment: As functions called by the button can't return anything for you to use, you either use globals or objects. If you feel the urge to refactor code, you should do it. Refactoring will give you better code and less problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, there is a way: use [tkinter variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-setting-and-retrieving-values-of-tkinter-variable/), instead of globals

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, BooleanVar
root = Tk()
root.title('Main')
root.minsize(400, 450)

toggle_tkinter = BooleanVar(value=True)

def change_now():
    root.config(bg='blue') if toggle_tkinter.get() else root.config(bg='black')
    toggle_tkinter.set(not toggle_tkinter.get())

my_button = Button(root, text='Click me!', command=change_now)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Though, I have personally found a case where globals make a decent design choice (sticking under the assumption that OOP is not viable): imagine that you have a 30 variables that you need to pass on to a checking function that validates the input and then uses only a subset of these variables (or a mixture of them), depending on the user input. In this case, instead of passing all 30 variables to your checker function and then your checker function passing whatever is needed onwards, I've opted to set them all as globals - that way they can be extracted and managed much more easily; see [here](https://github.com/nikbpetrov/mufos/blob/master/Source%20code/__ROOT.py) (the repo contains relevant READMEs and a paper describe the infrastructure) for such a use case if interested.

Comment: The variable is still a global object. This doesn’t avoid using globals.

Comment: @npetrov937 Thanks for your answer! I get the idea of what you explained seeing the code you shared. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Why do you think is wrong? Is it still a bad practice to do that?

Comment: Bryan just states that `toggle_tkinter` is still a global variable, the difference is that you don't need to call the line `global toggle_tkinter` inside `change_now()`.  He doesn't say it is wrong.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong. The OP asked how to not use global variables. I. Your answer `toggle_tkinter` is a global variable.

Comment: @BryanOakley We are getting lost in definitions I think. I cannot think of any way to achieve the desired functionality without the use of a variable declared outside of the scope of the function, which is how you operationalise `global`, whereas I think the OP was referring to not using the python `global` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the need to manage a global variable by using the background color as the Boolean. Set it to black if it’s currently blue, and blue if it’s black.

```
def chande_now():
    color = “black” if root.cget(“bg”) == “blue” else “blue”
    root.configure(bg=color)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know that method, seems pretty useful.